# Calendar getDisplayName for weekday gives different output in different Android versions

Tags: android, calendar

I am consuming an API that returns the opening hours of various businesses.

Hours come to me in this form:

```
[
  { "day": "monday", "isOpen": true, "open": "09:00", "close": "15:00"},
  { "day": "tuesday", "isOpen": true, "open": "09:00", "close": "15:00" },
  { "day": "wednesday", "isOpen": true, "open": "09:00", "close": "15:00" },
  { "day": "thursday", "isOpen": true, "open": "09:00", "close": "15:00" },
  { "day": "friday", "isOpen": true, "open": "09:00", "close": "15:00" },
  { "day": "saturday", "isOpen": false, "open": "", "close": "" },
  { "day": "sunday", "isOpen": false, "open": "", "close": "" },
]
```

I have the following function that is supposed to get today's hours from the list and display them (the `DaySchedule` type is a `data class` made from the data structure above):

```
fun todayWorkingHours(schedule: List<DaySchedule>): String {
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    val todayDay = cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.ROOT)!!.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)
    val workSchedule = schedule.find { it.day == todayDay }
        ?: return context.getString(R.string.non_working_day)

    if (workSchedule.isOpen) {
        val open = workSchedule.open
        val close = workSchedule.close
        return "${currentDay.capitalize(Locale.getDefault())}: $open - $close"
    }

    return "${currentDay.capitalize(Locale.getDefault())}: " + context.getString(R.string.non_working_day)
}
```

I have Android devices running version 7 (Samsung Galaxy S6) and 11 (Google Pixel 3a) to test with. On v7, this code works perfectly. However, on v11, it always returns the message in `R.string.non_working_day`.

Using the debugger, I determined that the problem is in the second line of the function:

- Android 7 - `todayDay` is `"tuesday"`
- Android 11 - `todayDay` is `"tue"`

How can I get all versions of Android to give me the full name of the day?

---

I also tried using the newer `java.time` API (with `coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled` for older OS versions):

```
val todayDay = DayOfWeek.from(LocalDate.now()).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ROOT).toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)
```

It does the same thing - it gives the correct `"tuesday"` on older versions and the incorrect `"tue"` on Android 11. While I could find little documentation about the older `Calendar` classes, [the Android docs for `java.time.format.TextStyle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/format/TextStyle) explicitly say that `TextStyle.LONG` should be giving me the full month name.

Comment: I know that matching on the names is not ideal, but it is all that the external API gives me.

Comment: Have you tried switching from `Locale.ROOT` to `Locale.getDefault()`?

Comment: @MatPag I can't do that because users with a different language set on their devices will have `getDefault()` return the text for their language instead of English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is a bug in `Locale.ROOT`. Switching to `Locale.ENGLISH` makes it work properly, and I know that the server will always be using English.

Thanks to [@MatPag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2910520/matpag) for the hint of what direction to look.

Comment: Bug filed: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180417187